# Form input getting null? using AngularJS and MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, angularjs

I'm getting null from inserting data to my database? I don't know what's the problem here's my form
[image: form]

here's what I get
[image: mysql]

This is my html code

```
<input id="bday" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="bday"
                               ng-class="{invalid : validation.bday}">
                        <label for="bday" ng-class="{invalid : validation.bday}"
                               data-error="Birth Date is required">Birth Date</label>
```

and I use a script to format the input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#bday').formatter({
        'pattern': '{{9999}}-{{99}}-{{99}}',
    });
</script>
```

and I get the data from my controller using

```
var userObj ={
                        "firstName":$scope.firstName,
                        "middleName":$scope.midName,
                        "lastName":$scope.lastName,
                        "username":$scope.username,
                        "password":$scope.password,
                        "emailAddress":$scope.email,
                        "gender":$scope.selectedGender,
                        "bday":$scope.bday,
                        "address":$scope.address,
                        "contactNo":$scope.contactNo


                    };
```

I turned off the validation for bday because I can't pass through it because its null but even its not validating anymore I get null

I can't see the problem here :(

its only String bday with normal getters setters

I also get the null when I use select input

please help :(

EDIT:

I found the problem. When I use formatter it returns null. It shouldn't be that way any ideas?

EDIT:
My scripts
[image]
[image]

Comment: (_oh no, an [un-hashed password](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) in the database and an SQL injection_)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I haven't configure security yet I just wanna fix the crud before I do it